# How to balance the dataset for binary classification with one class having multiple types?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, dataset, conv-neural-network

I am working on a face anti-spoofing problem where I have to classify between live and spoof photos. There are various types of spoof such as print, replay, mask etc. But the model is expected just to say if the input is live or spoof and not bother about the spoof type. Should I balance my training data such that the number of samples in live = spoof or live=print=replay=mask ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 0):

It might help to depend on your situation. You can decide to do it by comparing the score of your model with a dummy classifier(A classifier that predicts always 0/1). If your model returns the same score as this dummy classifier you can understand your model is just good as a dummy one. You can also artificially create that data and compare it with your base model. Since this is an area of trial and error, the best thing you can do is finding out via trying.